# Extract one word after a specific word on the same line

Tags: linux, bash, csh

How can I extract a word that comes after a specific word in Linux (csh)?
More precisely, I have a file which has a single line which looks like this:

```
[some useless data] --pe_cnt 100 --rd_cnt 1000 [some more data]
```

I want to extract the number **`100`** which is after the `--pe_cnt` word.
I cannot use sed as that works only if you want to extract an entire line. Maybe I can use awk?

Also, I have multiple files that have different values instead of `100` so I need something that extracts the value but doesn't depend on the value.

Comment: "awk" is one possibility.  For example,  `echo 5 4 | awk '{ print $2 }' ` should display "4".

Answer (score 34, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="--pe_cnt") print $(i+1)}' inputFile
```

Basically loop over each word of the line. When you find the first you are looking for, grab the next word and print it.

With `grep`:

```
grep -oP "(?<=--pe_cnt )[^ ]+" inputFile
```

Comment: You need to add a space at the end of the lookbehind pattern in grep.

Comment: Yep sorry didn't test it. Thank you! :)

Comment: N.B. `grep` on Mac OSX 10.8 doesn't have `-P`.

Comment: JS웃: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. The first command worked perfectly! The second command did not give any output though.

Comment: @Rahul Sorry I had missed a space in the look behind which was corrected by ctn. It should work now.

Comment: Works great! But can you explain the `grep` regexp, in particular what `(?<=--pe_cnt )` does?

Comment: Nevermind, it's a perl regexp using look around assertions, [as I found here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: The `sed` answer is more efficient and more idiomatic than this answer, and should probably be the most upvoted, if not the accepted answer.

Comment: your answer helped me a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

You can use sed. Just make a group of want you want to match and replace the whole line with the group:

```
sed -n 's/^.*pe_cnt\s\+\([0-9]\+\).*$/\1/p' file
```

Comment: There was an error in the pattern previously but it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a single-space character between `--pe_cnt` and `100`, you may be able to use lookahead and lookbehind assertions

```
grep -oP '(?<=--pe_cnt\s)\d+(?=\s+--rd_cnt)'
```

Comment: Probably don't even need the `--rd_cnt`, it doesn't necessarily matter what the following options are

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the tip. I'm a newbie to Linux so these tips help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the shortest version:

```
grep -oP 'pe_cnt \K[^ ]+' file
```