# To find a word and copy the following word with shell(ubuntu)?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

is there a posibility to find a word in a file and than to copy the following word?

Example:

```
abc="def"
bla="no_need"
line_i_need="information_i_need"
still_no_use="blablabla"
```

so the third line, is exactly the line i need!

is it possible to find this word with shell orders?

thanks for your support

Comment: possible duplicate of [linux: Extract one word after a specific word on the same line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371197/linux-extract-one-word-after-a-specific-word-on-the-same-line)

Comment: If that's your file format, you might consider whether you trust the data to be eval-safe. `source "$filename"; echo "$line_i_need"` is a security risk if the data can be influenced by untrusted sources, and a bug risk if the data isn't in genuine POSIX sh assignment format, but certainly easy.

Answer (score 1):

Using an `awk` with custom field separator it is much simpler:

```
awk -F '[="]+' '$1=="line_i_need"{print $2}' file
information_i_need
```

`-F '[="]+'` sets field separator as 1 or more of `=` or `"`

Answer (score 0):

Use grep:

```
grep file_name line_i_need
```

It will print:

```
line_i_need="information_i_need"
```

Comment: i only need : information_i_need, i don´t need the rest...how can i cut it out?

Answer (score 0):

This finds the line with grep an cuts the second column using `"` separator

```
 grep file_name line_i_need | cut -d '"' -f2
```

Comment: grep "file_name line_i_need" | cut -d '"' -f2 is correct?

Comment: it should be if your file looks like in the snippet you provided. Try it and if you have any problem write a comment, if it works, mark it as solved.

Comment: i mean you forget to mark the word you need with " "