# Bash: Read from variable after keyword and a space

Tags: bash, variables, html

I am trying to make a script that reads text from a website and then finds a keyword and saves the text after that keyword as a variable. I have already got the text from a website and stored it in a variable. I am now trying to get text after the 'Password:' keyword and save that as a variable. Also I am only trying to get the text after the keyword and nothing more. Here is a n example

```
sdf sdf sfasdf;jiasjdf sdfiasj;dfijq3ifj'qiwf2rfp Password: ThisIsThePartIWant 'aksjdfkjq'woejf'qopwef dfhjsd;fhasdjkfh asd;jfh;asdjhf; asdjkfha;sdjfh;asjdhf ;asjdhf; sd
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to figure it out. For anyone wondering, I wrote the text from the site into a file and then was able to use what i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371197/linux-extract-one-word-after-a-specific-word-on-the-same-line) in order to accomplish what I was doing.