# Fetch value after certain pattern in Unix

Tags: shell, awk, grep

This is the text that I have

```
Peer Addr 1.1.1.1, Intf Port-Channel0.1, State Up
VRF default, LAddr 1.1.1.1, LD/RD 090/592
Session state is Up and using echo function with 300 ms interval
Detect Time: 8000
Sched Delay: 1*TxInt: 3522100, 2*TxInt: 5, 3*TxInt: 0, GT 3*TxInt: 0
Registered protocols: isis bgp ospf
```

I want the values after Peer Addr, Intf and Registered protocols

Expected output

```
1.1.1.1 

Port-Channel0.1

isis bgp ospf
```

This is what I have tried

```
grep -oP "Peer Addr\s+\K\w+"
```

I am unable to get the required output. I am new to shell scripting and would be great if someone can help me out on this one. I don't want all the output in a single command. I would like to store these as three different variables

Comment: `grep -Po 'Peer Addr \K.*?(?=,)' file`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linux: Extract one word after a specific word on the same line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371197/linux-extract-one-word-after-a-specific-word-on-the-same-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='[\n,]\\s*' 'sub(/^(Peer Addr|Intf|Registered protocols:) /,"")' file
1.1.1.1
Port-Channel0.1
isis bgp ospf
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Po '(Peer Addr|Intf|protocols:) \K.*?(?=(,|$))' file
```

Output:

```
1.1.1.1
Port-Channel0.1
isis bgp ospf
```

> `-P PATTERN`: Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression.
>
> `-o`: Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.
>
> `\K`: If `\K` appears in a Perl regex, it causes the regex matcher to drop everything before that point.
>
> `(?=...)`: The captured match must be followed by `,` or end of line (`$`) but that part is dropped, too.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`, you could do something like this:

```
sed -rn 's/Peer Addr *([^,]+), */\1/;
         s/Intf *([^,]+),.*/\n\1/;
         s/Registered protocols: *//;
         ta;d;:a p'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"[, ]" '/^Peer Addr/{print $3"\n"$6} /^Registered protocols:/{sub(/Registered protocols: /,"");print}' File
```

Here `IFS` as `,` and .

`/^Peer Addr/{print $3"\n"$6}` : If a line starts with `Peer Addr` print `$3`( Here `1.1.1.1`) and `$6`( `Port-Channel0.1`).

`/^Registered protocols:/{sub(/Registered protocols: /,"");print}'`: If a line starts with `Registered protocols:` print entire line after removing the string `Registered protocols:` with `sub` awk function.

Comment: Could you explain how your answer works? As-is, it may do what the OP wants, but they may not find it very informative.

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.